# How to return a default value from windows/registry with golang

Tags: go, registry

I just want to return a (Default) string value in Windows registry with Golang

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer k.Close()

s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("(Default)") // It won't work
// s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("SystemRoot") // This is worked
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Windows system root is %q\n", s)
```

I run it in CMD admin mode but there was noting to see

Comment: Are you sure you have a "Default" string value in your registry? I'm afraid you don't have such a value. What is your windows version?

Comment: Yes actually any key has a Default String value in registry

Comment: And does it has a value set? The data is `(value not set)`. What kind of error or result did you received?

Comment: Yes I assigned 8 to Default  name and it returns "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Also I checked k.GetStringValue("(Default)") in other paths and it cannot return the value of default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it out!

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.ALL_ACCESS)
s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("") // The blank one refers to (Default)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that whilst regedit show the default value as `(Default)` (note the parentheses), actually you have to access without parentheses.

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer k.Close()

s, _, err := k.GetStringValue("Default")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Windows system root is %q\n", s)
```

Comment: It's not working! Please check it on your Windows machine. Thanks

Comment: Downvoting because this is just wrong.  "Default value" has a special meaning for registry keys, and in the API that corresponds to an empty or NULL name as per the accepted answer.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa