# Detect windows version in Go to figure out the starup folder

Tags: windows, go, winapi

Is there anyway to detect if the host operating system is XP, Vista, 7, 8, or 10?
`runtime.GOOS` just returns "windows".

The reason for this is because I'm trying to manipulate files in the startup folder.

On windows vista, 7, 8, 10 it's located at:

`%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

On windows XP it's located at:

`Documents and Settings\%username%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some Windows API for finding the Startup folder, which would be a much better way than try to locate it yourself.

Comment: The correct way would be to use the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) with a [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) of either [`FOLDERID_CommonStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx#FOLDERID_CommonStartup) or [`FOLDERID_Startup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx#FOLDERID_Startup) depending on which Startup folder you are interested in.

Comment: I had a look at `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, it says "minimum supported client: windows vista", does that mean this function will not work on XP?

Comment: Note that the concept of [*Known Folders*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb776911.aspx) and thus  `SHGetKnownFolderPath` was introduced in Vista, so for XP, you have to fall back on the deprecated [`SHGetFolderPath` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) with a [`CSIDL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx) of either [`CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx#CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP) or …

Comment: … [`CSIDL_STARTUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx#CSIDL_STARTUP). (Actually, note that there are about 6 different Startup folders on older Windows versions.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. So should I attempt to call `SHGetKnownFolderPath` and if that panics I must be on XP, so fall back to `SHGetFolderPath`? I just tried to use the deprecated one on win10 and it panicked "specified procedure can't be found", that is with the Shell32.dll.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the windows registry?

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry

[How to return a default value from windows/registry with golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998532/how-to-return-a-default-value-from-windows-registry-with-golang)

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    cv, _, err := k.GetStringValue("CurrentVersion")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CurrentVersion: %s\n", cv)

    pn , _, err := k.GetStringValue("ProductName")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ProductName: %s\n", pn)

    maj, _, err := k.GetIntegerValue("CurrentMajorVersionNumber")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CurrentMajorVersionNumber: %d\n", maj)

    min, _, err := k.GetIntegerValue("CurrentMinorVersionNumber")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CurrentMinorVersionNumber: %d\n", min)

    cb, _, err := k.GetStringValue("CurrentBuild")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CurrentVersion: %s\n", cb)    
}
```

This returns:

```
PS C:\Users\Adamar\Desktop> .\WindowsVersion.exe
CurrentVersion: 6.3
ProductName: Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation
CurrentMajorVersionNumber: 10
CurrentMinorVersionNumber: 0
CurrentVersion: 14393
```

Although in the newest version of windows you have to read the following keys to get the version: CurrentMajorVersionNumber & CurrentMinorVersionNumber

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the Windows version, use the [w32 library](https://github.com/gonutz/w32), a pure Go Win32 API wrapper.

It has w32.RtlGetVersion() which returns a struct containing (besides other things) MajorVersion and MinorVersion. These will report the correct Windows version that the program is running on.

You cannot rely on the function w32.GetVersion(). Theoretically you could use [this Windows version table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx) to know where you are but GetVersion only works for applications that have a correct manifest file which says that the program is for Windows 10. If you just compile with `go build` without a manifest file, GetVersion will still report Windows 8 (Windows version 6.2).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"
)

func main() {
    v := w32.RtlGetVersion()
    fmt.Println(v.MajorVersion, v.MinorVersion)
}
```

Note however, as others have stated correctly, that you should really be using the appropriate Win32 API functions to get the special folders in your case.

Comment: this returns `6.2` even in windows 10.

Comment: @majidarif You are right, GetVersion does not work, I updated my answer. Please consider removing your comment as it is now misleading for future readers.

Comment: The `RtlGetVersion` is missing from the `gonutz/w32` library, at least in its current version (a6f5759)

Comment: You will need to use `github.com/gonutz/w32/v2` which *does* include this function. Updated the code in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is old, but at the time of this writing (Jan 2023), you can use [RtlGetNtVersionNumbers](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys@v0.4.0/windows#RtlGetNtVersionNumbers), which is officially maintained by Go.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    maj, min, patch := windows.RtlGetNtVersionNumbers()
    fmt.Println(maj, min, patch)
}
```

which for me prints `10 0 22621`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on excellent on-point comments from Jörg W Mittag, this should make you started:

```golang
//go:build windows

package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
    path, err := windows.KnownFolderPath(windows.FOLDERID_Startup, 0)
    fmt.Println(err, path)
}
```

See `syscall_windows.go` and `zknownfolderids_windows.go` at https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sys/+/master:windows for more info.

---

Note that [the last version of Go to support WinXP was 1.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137098), the current one is 1.19, and the support is provided for the two last versions, hence the last supported version as of now, 2023-01-10, is 1.18.
I mean, the need to make it work on WinXP is moot: a program built for Windows using Go 1.14+ won't even start on that platform.