# Go after 1.10 and support of Windows XP

Tags: go, windows-xp

First of all: I know that Windows XP is end of life, insanely insecure, a big risk and that everyone still using it will be doomed for ever.
Nonetheless I have to provide an application that can also run on Windows XP and I do so using Go.
In 1.10 it was announced that XP will no longer be supported and 1.11 confirms this in the [release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.11):

> As announced in the Go 1.10 release notes, Go 1.11 now requires
>   OpenBSD 6.2 or later, macOS 10.10 Yosemite or later, or Windows 7 or
>   later; support for previous versions of these operating systems has
>   been removed.

I compiled my application with 1.11 and tried to execute it on a Windows XP SP3 virtual machine. It could be executed successfully !
Then I thought that the revoked support for Windows XP only applies to the development toolchain but even that can still be executed on Windows XP:
[image]

As you can see the main go binary still runs on XP too. Is it already known when it will no longer be possible to run golang compiled exes on Windows XP because of technical limitations  or if certain methods will fail because they can no longer work because of missing APIs on XP ?

Comment: Dropping support generally doesn't mean that a thing is guaranteed not to work--but rather that it's not guaranteed to work. No doubt, certain features of Go 1.11 and/or the standard library will fail on Windows XP. As long as you don't use those features, there's a reasonable chance your software will work just fine.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted (it wasn't me). But asking people to explain their downvotes really isn't appropriate. They're anonymous for a reason.

Comment: @Marged, I'd say your question is simply [not on-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and that's why it gets downvoted. I, personally, find this question both interesting and supposedly useful to some folks (because I think I was in your boots, that is to say) but this does not change the fact it's off-topic. You would have been better off posting it to the mailing list instead.

Comment: @kostix: If it's off-topic, it should get VtCed, not DVed. At present, there are no close votes at all. So the off-topic theory doesn't seem to be very substantiated. Personally, I think the question is perfectly on-topic, and also not worthy of a downvote. The only reason I didn't up-vote is that the answer seems rather self-evident, so not especially interesting.

Comment: A quick search of the source revealed a couple of (minor) features that were on hold because of the need to support XP. You'll probably be fine if you never run across them. But of course, if you still have an XP machine, you need to take it out back and shoot it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks you, is there a specific text I could search for in order to find the features you mentioned ?

Comment: I searched github.com/golang/go for "Windows XP".

Comment: @MichaelHampton OK, that sounds feasible ;-)

Comment: Perfectly on-topic question, and one I had myself, thanks.  Also "everyone still using it will be doomed for ever" is quite chuckleworthy, hehe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Issue #23380](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23380) is the relevant discussion.

In short:

> Note that even if 1.10 is the last version to support XP, you'd get bugfix backports until 1.11 is out, and security backports until 1.12 is out. That means until January 2019 <…>

---

As to supporting Windows XP, there are both technical and non-technical reasons.
Supporting a platform requires:

- Someone who has access to it, and an incentive to work on it
  (either paid or unpaid).

  The most active Go-on-Windows developer, Alex Brainman,
  seems to have no interest in XP anymore.
- This platform must be supported on autobuilders which are part of the Go release / QA process.

  An autobuilder must be supported by someone.
- Bugs specific to a platform must be fixed and *tested.*

  For instance, that issue refers to [#23375](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23375) which happens only on Windows XP (SP3).
  But even if a bug was specific to Windows in general—as opposed
  to Windows XP, a fix for it would have to be tested on XP anyway.

Hence, unfortunately, if there is no interest in supported Go on Windows XP coming from some "powerful entities"—such as corporations—the best you can do is to actually work towards still supporting this by yourself, FWIW.

---

Also note that even after the support is officially ended, you still might have success building newer Go releases  from the source (which is reasonably simple since Go 1.5 as Go is now built using (an older release of) Go).

Hence a real show-stopper would be the Go team hitting some roadblock which would just *require* some kernel feature not present in Windows XP.
A good example was [some difficulty with SEH handling on Windows 2000](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/n2QQUxdltd0/discussion) which eventually led to dropping support for that OS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful. It would be interesting to know when/if it is planned to add Windows 7 only API calls or even "worse" to have the compiler produce binaries that are marked as Windows 7 only (in the PE header or alike). As long as I can create a binary I can test it in my dead platform and hope for the best ;-)

Comment: @Marged, that's not really a question for SO. Please post a message to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).

Comment: Thanks again, I will do so. I didn't find the relevant issue but with your help I was able to

Comment: @Marged, one last note you might find useful. I somewhat share you pain as I had to support some stuff working on XP at my ex-$dayjob for up to 2016 (and they still have it lingering in parts of the infrastructure). And from my experiece, the way you usually do this is to "get frozen" along with the platform. For instance, we still had copies of Delphi 7 to do occasional bugfixing of some oldish piece of software. D7 was as unmaintained as XP, even _more_ unmaintained, I'd say.

Comment: @Marged,  I mean, after Go really seizes working on XP you still may clutch on the last version which did; fixing 3rd-party packages to work with that Go version may be easier than trying to get a fresh Go version to build. And as to security issues, you have them anyway with your platform so… oh, well ;-)

Comment: I know the situation, I still have djgpp in my toolbox when I need to update software on MS-DOS ;-)

Comment: I guess now is the time: I built a program with golang 1.14.2 and when I run it on Windows XP I get …"is no valid win32 application"

Comment: @Marged, just to be sure: if you're cross-compiling on an `amd64` platform, are you sure you make Go build for `386`?

Comment: Yes and I checked it with a PE dumper