# Go 1.21 Windows Compatibility

Tags: go

The Go 1.20 [release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20#windows) mention

> Go 1.20 is the last release that will run on any release of Windows 7, 8, Server 2008 and Server 2012. Go 1.21 will require at least Windows 10 or Server 2016.

The Go 1.21 [release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.21#windows) reiterate this

> As announced in the Go 1.20 release notes, Go 1.21 requires at least Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016; support for previous versions has been discontinued.

However, one thing is unclear to me. Is this just referring to installation / using the sdk itself, or does this apply to the ability to run binaries compiled with Go 1.21 as well?

Comment: Compiled binaries for the correct architecture will still run

Comment: That decision might have either of the reasons–requirements for the tooling and requirements for the binaries it provides,–and, which is more likely,–both of them. Back then I've presented [the reasons for dropping support for WinXP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52137703/720999) to someone here on SO with a question like yours. To understand, why there may be both reasons, consider that Go is written in Go (since 1.4 or so), and hence if Go wants to have the system to provide some feature to a compiled program written in Go, this equally applies to the tooling written in Go.

Comment: There relevant issues are [#57003](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57003) and [#57004](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57004) (and [that is how to find them](https://github.com/golang/go/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3AOS-Windows+milestone%3AGo1.21)).

Comment: …and [an interesting point](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52188#issuecomment-1332625934) in another issue regarding policy for supporting OS versions. Well, so, to summarize, in this particular case, the deprecation notice appears to be not caused by real requirements for, say, specific kernel features, and you might have luck building and running programs for/on those Windows versions using Go 1.21, but should you report a bug which only manifests itself on a deprecated OS, it will likely be closed as "wontfix".

Comment: @kostix thanks for the replies. So basically nothing is expectedly to be inherently broken in those deprecated operating systems, and Go 1.21 binaries _should_ work on the older systems, but if anything goes wrong there won't be any support for it

Comment: @aarbor, yes, I would say so.

Comment: BTW #57003 links to [an interesting issue](https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/3588) which is about making DNS resolving on Windows not consume an OS thread during the whole duration of a call, and the relevant Win32 API issue requires Windows 8 and above. If/when the Go's internal DNS resolving code switches to that call, the requirement for the lowest OS version becomes material. Sure, it's possible to make the code fallback to an older API call at runtime but I doubt such an effort is going to be made in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to produced binaries as well.
Example given [Syncthing 1.27 broke on Win7](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/9282) because it uses Go 1.21.